# Find and replace text in header and footer - MS-Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently at college and whenever we have to do an assignment we need to use the template provided. I would like to make a script in Word (OS X 2016 version) that replaces the default text. I have got it to work in the normal document so far but not the headers or footers. Here is the code I have so far

```
Sub FrontPage()
'
' FrontPage Macro
'
'

teachersName = InputBox("Please enter teachers Name", "Teachers Name", "")
assignmentTitle = InputBox("Please Enter the assignment title", "Assignment Title", "")
assignmentNumber = InputBox("Please Enter the assignment number", "Assignment Number", "")
dueDay = InputBox("What day does it need to be handed in by", "Due Day", "Monday")
dueDate = InputBox("What date does it need to be handed in by", "Due Date", "20")

dueMonth = InputBox("What month does it need to be handed in by", "Due Month", "June")


With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
.Text = "[2/3]"
.Replacement.Text = "2"
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With


With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
.Text = "[HARDWARE/SOFTWARE]"
.Replacement.Text = "HARDWARE"
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With


With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
.Text = "[Your_Name]"
.Replacement.Text = "My Name"
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With


With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
.Text = "[Teachers_Name]"
.Replacement.Text = teachersName
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With


With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
.Text = "[Assignment_Title]"
.Replacement.Text = assignmentTitle
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With


With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
.Text = "[Assignment_Number/ref]"
.Replacement.Text = assignmentNumber
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With


With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
.Text = "[Monday, 20 June 2011]"
.Replacement.Text = dueDay + ", " + dueDate + " " + dueMonth + " 2015"
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With


End Sub
```

The only issue is the code between the `with` section does not work on headers or footers. I have looked at [both answers from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996531/search-and-replace-in-msword-header-and-footer-using-delphi-xe3) however the code is highlighted in red saying it is wrong. Also when I try 'step 1' from [this site](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm) I also get the same error.

In the header I want to change `[Unit_Number]` to a new variable (given by InputBox), `[Unit Name]` to `assignmentTitle` variable and `[assignment_number]` to `assignmentNumber` variable.

In the footer I would like to replace `[Your_Name]` with the text 'My Name'.

How would I go about doing this since what I have tried so far does not work?

Comment: you need to explore `StoryRanges` in your document. Both `Footers` and `Headers` are different `StoryRanges` not included in main document `Content` (`MainTextStory`).

Comment: @KazimierzJawor Is that why the code has been displaying as red then?

Comment: code in read means only there is a syntax error. I don't know to which answer you refer as you linked question, not the answer.

Comment: @KazimierzJawor Sorry about that, I meant from both. It may be I didn't understand the answers that well since this is my first word program. I also copied and pasted the code in the question and that was in red too.

Comment: for sure both answers have some kind of references to `StoryRanges`. Do not use `semicolon` at the and of the line which results with syntax error in VBA (red code).

Comment: @KazimierzJawor For the external link on step 1 I got an error on the line beginning with `For` and `With` then again on `.Execute` and `End`. Is the code wrong or does it need updating for 2016 or could my code be causing it to error out?